# SQL, Change the number value of a field. In Visual basic

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

Im programming a business application as part of an assignment and ran across a problem I have never had to face before.

Im wondering is it possible to update the value of the field QuantityonHand in this statement WITHOUT grabbing it first with another statement and assigning it to a variable.

Google is turning up nothing like what im looking for, thanks!

```
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Inventory SET QuantityOnHand = ? WHERE ProductID = ?", Con)

        Prm = New OleDbParameter("QuantityOnHand ", )
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Prm)

        Prm = New OleDbParameter("ProductID ", "003")
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Prm)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Are you trying to increase/decrease the `QuantityOnHand`? If yes then you can do like `SET QuantityOnHand = QuantityOnHand + ?`

Comment: `UPDATE Inventory SET QuantityOnHand = (QuantityOnHand  + ?) WHERE ProductID = ?`  pass positives to increase, negative vals to decrease

Comment: Ah so you can do it like that? Thanks. That seems like it will be perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer is pretty poor.  You wisety used Parameters, so just embed an expression in the SQL:

```
UPDATE Inventory SET QuantityOnHand = (QuantityOnHand  + ?) WHERE ProductID = ?
```

pass positives to increase, negative vals to decrease

Comment: I'll just remove mine in favor of yours. I think I misunderstood what he was trying to say.